# Can not access weblogic console from a different machine

Tags: linux, networking, telnet, firewall, weblogic12c

I am having trouble accessing the weblogic console from a different machine in the same network.

I installed weblogic on a server from a different machine by ssh. The weblogic is up and running, but now I can't access the console on a browser from my machine. Both machines are part of the same network.

I am able to SSH in to the server from my local machine. Ping also works on both machines using each other's IP address.

`telnet` gives me the following output:

```
am@Linux-Vostro-3250:~$ telnet 192.x.x.x 7002
Trying 192.x.x.x...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
```

This is confusing me, because I am able to access the server using `ssh`.

I searched everywhere for a possible solution, but I could only find more problems.

In very simple language, how do I resolve this issue or what exactly may the cause be?

Comment: Firewall, most likely, is blocking this port. SSh is using port 22.

Comment: yes. There was no firewall set up in the server.

Comment: it can also be the firewall on the other end, is it also a Linux machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no firewall cinfigured in the server. I set up a firewall by following the instructions from this site "https://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/linux-firewall"

There are two GUI options but none of them worked for me so better stick to the CLI.

then, using the following command i granted access to my local machine from the server :

```
# Accept packets from specific host (x.x.x.x).
iptables -A INPUT -s x.x.x.x -j ACCEPT
```

Now i can access the Weblogic console from my x.x.x.x machine.